# And then in the C++ conditional

Tags: c++, if-statement, ada

Ada has nice feature of `and then` statement used in the `if` condition in addition to the [Boolean `and` operator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Keywords/and). This allows for checking if, e.g., the object is not null before accessing it like so:

```
if Object /= null and then Object.Value > 5 then
   -- do something with the value
end if;
```

Is there a way to express a similar behaviour in C++ w/o using a nested `if`?

Comment: just use if ((obj != null) && (object.value > 5)). c++ will evaluate left to right and stop evaluating && when the first in the chain is  false

Comment: The `and` or `&&` operator has fixed order of evaluation

Comment: `if (foo) foo->bar()` ??

Comment: In Ada, there is also an `and` operator, which is a Boolean and operator as explained here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Keywords/and

Comment: thanks for the link. In C++ `and` corresponds to the ada `and then` and I wouldnt even know from the top of my head to write a "non-shortcircuiting and"  ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thank you for the comment. Added the link to the question.

Comment: @formerlyknownas To prevent short circuiting, you could assign the evaluation of  the operands to two different named variables  and then perform the and on the results.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, `Object` cannot be NULL in C++ in your code as it seems not to be a pointer. If it were a pointer you could say:

```
 if (Object && Object->Value > 5 ) {
       // do something
 }
```

In C++ the `&&` operator performs "short-circuited evaluation" - the evaluation stops if a left-most operand  evaluates to false.

Comment: To expand on Neil's answer, the || operator also does short-circuit evaluation.  For most other operators, the order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified.

Comment: @Dave comma-operator and conditional-operator also specify evaluation order. Also the `.` and `->` operator. I'm sure there are others that I have forgotten :-)

Comment: @NeoSer just make sure not to use `&` instead as it does not have short-circuit, you may prefer use alias `and` instead to avoid confusion

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't seem to be a pointer (or access value, as its called in Ada)? Ada can easily have an variable called `Object` of an access type: `type Foo is access Bar;` and then `Object : Foo;`

Comment: To expand on @egilhh’s comment, `Object.Value` is a legal dereferencing, shorthand for `Object.all.Value`